# Use Sed to cut out the seconds from a date

Tags: linux, replace, sed

I have a list of url data in a file that looks like this:

```
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 3:30:39 PM
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 9:30:30 AM
    https://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 13:30:30 PM
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 10:30:39 AM
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 3:30 PM
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 9:30 AM
    https://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 13:30 PM
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 10:30 AM
```

Basically to remove the :XX seconds part from the line using sed.  I also don't mind if it deletes everything after the minutes as well.  I can use sed or cut since I'm using batch file scripting.  Can anyone help ?

So far I've tried the following:

```
sed 's/.*:([^,*]*) AM/\1/g' file.txt
```

Comment: sed 's/.*:\([^,*]*\) AM/\1/g' file.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this `sed -r 's/(.*):[0-9]{2}(.*)/\1\2/'`:

```
$ cat file
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 3:30:39 PM
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 9:30:30 AM
    https://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 13:30:30 PM
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 10:30:39 AM

$ sed -r 's/(.*):[0-9]{2}(.*)/\1\2/' file
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 3:30 PM
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 9:30 AM
    https://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 13:30 PM
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 10:30 AM
```

Explanation:

```
(.*):     # Capture everything up the last : (greedy)
[0-9]{2}  # Match the two digits 
(.*)      # Capture the rest of the line

\1\2      # Replace with the two captured groups
```

Note: `-r` use extended regular expressions, could be `-E` dependent on your `sed` flavor, check with the  `man`.

**Edit:**

```
$ sed -r 's/[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} /00 /' file
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 3:00 PM
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 9:00 AM
    https://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 13:00 PM
    http://site.com/some/site.htm,12/5/2012 10:00 AM
```

Comment: AWESOME! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! You are a SED GOD! ha ha.  I need this because I need to weed out duplicates, much help!

Comment: I have to wait 2 minutes to accept your answer, that is how fast you were to respond!  :-)

Comment: Just curious, would be hard to just show something like 9:00 AM , 10:00 etc.  basically changes the minutes to :00  ?

Comment: honestly you are amazing with sed ... I can figure out a lot of technical things but sed expert is a special class of super human... ha ha ... I think I need to find a good sed book if you know of one. Anyway, Thanks again.. greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, just look for 2 digits after a colon followed by a space, and replace with just the space.

```
sed 's/:[0-9][0-9] / /g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A really simple solution:

```
sed 's/:.. / /' file
```

But this is probably not recommended as it is too generic, and likely to go wrong if the formatting changes even slightly.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
sed -r 's/...( [AP]M)$/\1/' file.txt
```

Matches on lines ending with a space followed by AM or PM, and removes whatever three characters preceded it.

The `$` matches on end of line, the parenthesis keeps the `AM` or `PM` so you can reference it with the `\1` in the substitution text.  The `-r` command-line option allows use of extended regular expressions (needed for the `\1` reference).